# How to fetch the last character in URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, let's say http://www.google.com/Stack/overflow

In this above example, overflow is the last character. I need to fetch that overflow character

Please help me to achieve this

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: `window.location.href[window.location.href.length -1]` :P

Comment: Last character, or last path segment?

Comment: @varun this will throw the last letter as http://google.com/varun o/p as "n" rite i nee varun the whole word

Comment: @Shyam Then your question is wrong mate! A character is a single unit!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

This splits the URL and returns the last element of that array using `.pop()`.

Comment: great sort and sweet...+1 from me